# Uncaught TypeError: lineChart.Line is not a function in chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js

while creating line chart in chartjs getting error-

> "Uncaught TypeError: lineChart.Line is not a function"

. find the jsfiddler link below

https://jsfiddle.net/chx9fj7a/9/

throwing error in below line

```
 lineChart.Line(areaChartData, lineChartOptions)
```

html

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!-- LINE CHART -->
                        <div class="box box-info">
                            <div class="box-header with-border">
                                <h3 class="box-title">Line Chart</h3>
                                <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
                                        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="chart">
                                    <canvas id="oltmsVoltageChart" style="height:250px"></canvas>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.box-body -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chx9fj7a/9/

code

```
$(function () {
        var areaChartData = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Electronics',
                fillColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                strokeColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                pointColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                pointStrokeColor: '#c1c7d1',
                pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
            },
            {
                label: 'Digital Goods',
                fillColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
                strokeColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
                pointColor: '#3b8bba',
                pointStrokeColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
                pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
                data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
            }
        ]
    }

    var areaChartOptions = {
        //Boolean - If we should show the scale at all
        showScale: true,
        //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
        scaleShowGridLines: false,
        //String - Colour of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.05)',
        //Number - Width of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
        //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
        scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
        //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
        scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
        //Boolean - Whether the line is curved between points
        bezierCurve: true,
        //Number - Tension of the bezier curve between points
        bezierCurveTension: 0.3,
        //Boolean - Whether to show a dot for each point
        pointDot: false,
        //Number - Radius of each point dot in pixels
        pointDotRadius: 4,
        //Number - Pixel width of point dot stroke
        pointDotStrokeWidth: 1,
        //Number - amount extra to add to the radius to cater for hit detection outside the drawn point
        pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
        //Boolean - Whether to show a stroke for datasets
        datasetStroke: true,
        //Number - Pixel width of dataset stroke
        datasetStrokeWidth: 2,
        //Boolean - Whether to fill the dataset with a color
        datasetFill: true,
        //String - A legend template
        legendTemplate: '<ul class="<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style="background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>',
        //Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
        responsive: true
    }

    var lineChartCanvas = $('#oltmsVoltageChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
    var lineChart = new Chart(lineChartCanvas)
    var lineChartOptions = areaChartOptions
    lineChartOptions.datasetFill = false
    lineChart.Line(areaChartData, lineChartOptions)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is correct; `line()` isn't a function (at least not that I can find).

You should pass `line` as the `type` option when creating the chart:

```
var lineChart = new Chart(lineChartCanvas,{
    type: 'line',
    data: areaChartData,
    options: lineChartOptions
})
```

```js
$(function() {
  var areaChartData = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Electronics',
        fillColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#c1c7d1',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
      },
      {
        label: 'Digital Goods',
        fillColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
        pointColor: '#3b8bba',
        pointStrokeColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
      }
    ]
  }

  var areaChartOptions = {
    //Boolean - If we should show the scale at all
    showScale: true,
    //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
    scaleShowGridLines: false,
    //String - Colour of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.05)',
    //Number - Width of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
    //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
    scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
    //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
    scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
    //Boolean - Whether the line is curved between points
    bezierCurve: true,
    //Number - Tension of the bezier curve between points
    bezierCurveTension: 0.3,
    //Boolean - Whether to show a dot for each point
    pointDot: false,
    //Number - Radius of each point dot in pixels
    pointDotRadius: 4,
    //Number - Pixel width of point dot stroke
    pointDotStrokeWidth: 1,
    //Number - amount extra to add to the radius to cater for hit detection outside the drawn point
    pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
    //Boolean - Whether to show a stroke for datasets
    datasetStroke: true,
    //Number - Pixel width of dataset stroke
    datasetStrokeWidth: 2,
    //Boolean - Whether to fill the dataset with a color
    datasetFill: true,
    //String - A legend template
    legendTemplate: '<ul class="<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style="background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>',
    //Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
    responsive: true
  }

  var lineChartCanvas = $('#oltmsVoltageChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
  var lineChartOptions = areaChartOptions
   var lineChart = new Chart(lineChartCanvas,{
                type: 'line',
                data: areaChartData,
                options: lineChartOptions
            })
  lineChartOptions.datasetFill = false
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <!-- LINE CHART -->
  <div class="box box-info">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
      <h3 class="box-title">Line Chart</h3>
      <div class="box-tools pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
                                        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                    </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="chart">
        <canvas id="oltmsVoltageChart" style="height:250px"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a46x2djb/